# add two-dimensional name on a list

Tags: r

I want to add two dimensions on the name of the list.
For example,

```
N <- 3
M <- 2
x <- list()
for(i in 1:N) {
  for(j in 1:M){
  Ps <- i  
  x[[paste0("element", i)]] <- Ps
  }
}

>x
$element1
[1] 1

$element2
[1] 2

$element3
[1] 3

However, I want to return a result like:

$element1,method1
[1] 1

$element1,method2
[1] 1

$element2,method1
[1] 2

$element2,method2
[1] 2

$element3,method1
[1] 3

$element3,method2
[1] 3
```

I guess building a three-dimensional "array" may work well on this problem, but I need to use a list because multiple hierarchical time series forecast results only can be stored in a list but cannot be stored in an array. Anyone who can help me solve it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use nested lists

```
x[[paste0("element", i)]][[paste0("method", j)]] <- list(Ps)
```

or simply make character strings describing what you have

```
x[[paste0("element", i, ",method", j)]] <- Ps
```